# C++ function that takes args Eigen sparse matrices

Tags: c++, function, sparse-matrix, eigen

Eigen library provides/suggests numerous ways to pass a dense matrix in a function, so that it works for a different types that share the same base, and avoids copying (i.e. Ref<>, template expressions).

However, I haven't found anything equivalent for sparse matrices in either eigen documentation or online.

I basically have the following question:
How can I write a function with a generic interface so it can be called with both SparseMatrix or MappedSparseMatrix objects, of potentially different template arguments, without copying?

I have tried template expression of SparseMatrixBase withe derived arguments but I couldn't make it work.

A simple example code will be appreciated.

Comment: In the devel branch you can use `Ref<SparseMatrix<...> >` and `Map<SparseMatrix<...> >` as with dense objects. This also makes `MappedSparseMatrix` deprecated.

Comment: That's great. How about the case that I want to support sparse matrices with different template parameters, say double/float, row major/col major?

Comment: Then use a template function taking a `SparseMatrixBase<Derived>`.

Comment: I have tried it. But it doesn't seem to work with MappedSparseMatrix. Can you give me a simple example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply write a template function taking any `SparseMatrixBase<Derived>`, for instance:

```
template<typename Derived>
void foo(const SparseMatrixBase<Derived> &a_mat) {
    const Derived &mat(a_mat.derived());
    SparseMatrix<typename Derived::Scalar> tr_mat = mat.transpose();
}
```